How to make a customized bullet text box in HTML/Javascript?
I am trying to make a custom text box in HTML/Javascript with the following requirements:

The text box's initial state will be a single bullet point like this:

Every line must start with a bullet point, so when the user types "enter" it will go to a new line and automatically start it with a bullet point
If they press "backspace" on an empty line with only a bullet point, it deletes the bullet point and returns to the end of the previous line
Bullet points are idented with "tab"
Bullet points are un-idented with "shift + tab"
Bullet points can only be indented once
Supports copy and pasted text

The following image is a word text box that I am trying to emulate:

I have tried a couple of solutions, but none seem to work the way I want. Is there something easy I am missing?
Edit: This is one of the versions I attempted. It fits all requirements, except it does not let me highlight text between different lines (ie. if i want to bulk delete stuff, I need to do it one point at a time)
Here is a demo: https://js.do/noahsb1/bulletpoint-textbox
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Text Editor with Line-Starting Bullet Points</title>
<style>
.editor {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: text;
}
.line {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.bullet {
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.editable {
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 20px;
    outline: none;
}

.editable:focus {
    outline: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor" class="editor" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="line">
        <span class="bullet">•</span>
        <div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
    const selection = document.getSelection();

    editor.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        const line = getLineElementFromSelection();
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            const cursorPosition = range.startOffset;

            const line = getLineElementFromSelection();
            const editable = line.querySelector('.editable');
            const textContent = editable.textContent;
            
            const textBeforeCursor = textContent.substring(0, cursorPosition);
            const textAfterCursor = textContent.substring(cursorPosition);
            
            editable.textContent = textBeforeCursor;
            
            const newline = createNewLine();
            const newEditable = newline.querySelector('.editable');
            newEditable.textContent = textAfterCursor;
            insertAfter(newline, line);
            newEditable.focus();
        } else if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
            if (selection.isCollapsed && selection.anchorOffset === 0) {
                if (line.classList.contains('line') && editor.children.length > 1) {
                    let adjacentEditable;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    const editable = line.querySelector('.editable');
                    const text = editable.textContent;
                    
                    if (line.previousElementSibling) {
                        adjacentEditable = line.previousElementSibling.querySelector('.editable');
                        adjacentEditable.textContent += text;
                    } else if (line.nextElementSibling) {
                        adjacentEditable = line.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.editable');
                        if(text.length !== 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    editor.removeChild(line);
                    adjacentEditable.focus();
                    const range = document.createRange();
                    const sel = window.getSelection();
                    range.selectNodeContents(adjacentEditable);
                    range.collapse(false);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                } else if (editor.children.length === 1) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        } else if (e.key === 'Delete') {
            const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            const editable = getLineElementFromSelection().querySelector('.editable');
    
            const cursorPosition = range.endOffset;
            const textLength = editable.textContent.length;

            if (cursorPosition === textLength) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (line.nextElementSibling) {
                    let adjacentEditable = line.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.editable');
                    editable.textContent += adjacentEditable.textContent;
                    editor.removeChild(line.nextElementSibling);
                    
                    const newRange = document.createRange();
                    const newSelection = window.getSelection();
                    newRange.setStart(editable.childNodes[0], textLength);
                    newRange.collapse(true);
                    newSelection.removeAllRanges();
                    newSelection.addRange(newRange);
                }
            }
        } else if (e.key === 'Tab' && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let indentLevel = parseInt(line.getAttribute('data-indent-level')) || 0;
            if (line !== editor.firstElementChild && indentLevel < 1) {
                indentLevel++;
                line.setAttribute('data-indent-level', indentLevel.toString());
                const currentMarginLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(line).marginLeft, 10);
                line.style.marginLeft = `${currentMarginLeft + 20}px`;
                const bullet = line.querySelector('.bullet');
                bullet.innerHTML = '◦';
            }
        } else if (e.key === 'Tab' && e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let indentLevel = parseInt(line.getAttribute('data-indent-level')) || 0;
            if (line !== editor.firstElementChild && indentLevel > 0) {
                indentLevel--;
                line.setAttribute('data-indent-level', indentLevel.toString());
                const currentMarginLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(line).marginLeft, 10);
                line.style.marginLeft = `${currentMarginLeft - 20}px`;
                const bullet = line.querySelector('.bullet');
                bullet.innerHTML = '•';
            }
        } else if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (line.previousElementSibling) {
                let adjacentEditable = line.previousElementSibling.querySelector('.editable');
                adjacentEditable.focus();
            }
        } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (line.nextElementSibling) {
                let adjacentEditable = line.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.editable');
                adjacentEditable.focus();
            }
        }
    });
    
    editor.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const line = getLineElementFromSelection();
        const text = (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text');
        const lines = text.split(/\r?\n/).map(line => line.replace(/^•/gm, '')
                            .replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ''));
        const currentLine = getLineElementFromSelection();
        console.log(lines)
        
        lines.forEach((lineText, index) => {
            if (index === 0) {
                const editable = line.querySelector('.editable');
                editable.textContent += lineText;
                editable.focus();
            } else {
                const newline = createNewLine();
                const editable = newline.querySelector('.editable');
                editable.textContent = lineText;
                insertAfter(newline, line);
            }
        });
    });

    function createNewLine() {
        const newline = document.createElement('div');
        newline.classList.add('line');
        const bullet = document.createElement('span');
        bullet.classList.add('bullet');
        bullet.innerHTML = '•';
        const editable = document.createElement('div');
        editable.classList.add('editable');
        editable.contentEditable = true;
        newline.appendChild(bullet);
        newline.appendChild(editable);
        return newline
    }

    function getLineElementFromSelection() {
        let node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
        while (node && !node.classList?.contains('line')) {
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    
        return node;
    }

    function insertAfter(newElement, referenceElement) {
        const parent = referenceElement.parentNode;
        if (parent.lastChild === referenceElement) {
            parent.appendChild(newElement);
        } else {
            parent.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement.nextSibling);
        }
    }   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>


"I have tried a couple of solution" .... Could you show at least one approach you tried?

@GetSet, the solutions I have tried are all very messy and just poorly coded. They are all pure typescript attempts. The point of my question was asking if there were any technologies that I should be looking at to make this easier.

I didnt downvote you but the point of the forum is to ask questions that are on topic, which in your case, a coding attempt if you have one, will help others help you debug/improve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@GetSet, I have added an example of what I have tried. Thank you.

You can do this by using JavaScript, jQuery, and HTML. (CSS Is optional)
Place this in your head:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

Place this in your body:
<textarea id="customTextbox" rows="4">• </textarea>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customTextbox").on("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                char("\n• ");
            }
            if (e.which == 9) {
                e.preventDefault();
                char("\n  ○ ");
            }
        });
    });
    function char(text) {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("customTextbox");
        var CP = textbox.selectionStart;
        var TBC = textbox.value.substring(0, CP);
        var TAC = textbox.value.substring(CP, textbox.value.length);
        textbox.value = TBC + text + TAC;
        textbox.selectionStart = textbox.selectionEnd = CP + text.length;
        textbox.focus();
    }
</script>

Now you're done. You should have a working text box.
Pressing "Enter" will make a new line and a solid bullet point.
Pressing "Tab" will make a new indent and an empty bullet point.
Right now this code does not delete the bullet point with backspace, but I will soon edit this post and add that.
Edit:
I've added the function for deleting the lines. Replace the original <script> code with this.
<script>
    char("• ");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customTextbox").on("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                char("\n• ");
            }
            if (e.which == 9) {
                e.preventDefault();
                char("\n  ○ ");
            }
            if (e.which == 8) {
                del(e);
            }
        });
    });
    function char(text) {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("customTextbox");
        var CP = textbox.selectionStart;
        var TBC = textbox.value.substring(0, CP);
        var TAC = textbox.value.substring(CP, textbox.value.length);
        textbox.value = TBC + text + TAC;
        textbox.selectionStart = textbox.selectionEnd = CP + text.length;
        textbox.focus();
    }
    function del(e) {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("customTextbox");
        var CP = textbox.selectionStart;
        var text = textbox.value;
        var lines = text.split("\n");
        var CLI = textbox.value.substr(0, CP).split("\n").length - 1;
        if (CLI > 0) {
            var currentLine = lines[CLI];
            var previousLineLength = lines[CLI - 1].length;
            if (currentLine === "• " || currentLine === "  ○ ") {
                e.preventDefault();
                lines.splice(CLI, 1);
                textbox.value = lines.join("\n");
                var NCP = textbox.value.substr(0, CP - previousLineLength - 1).length;
                textbox.selectionStart = textbox.selectionEnd = NCP;
            } else {
                lines[CLI] = lines[CLI].substring(0, CP - previousLineLength - 1) + lines[CLI].substring(CP);
                textbox.value = lines.join("\n");
                var NCP = textbox.value.substr(0, CP).length;
                textbox.selectionStart = textbox.selectionEnd = NCP;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

This is some very basic code so it's not the best method, but it works.
Also, remove the "• " in the <textarea>.
I made an example on js.do which you can find at https://js.do/code/custom-textbox

Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, this does not fit all my requirements. If you wouldn't mind checking out the attempt I just uploaded. Thanks again.
